# How can I include shortcodes within PHP?

Tags: php, shortcode

I have a WordPress site using the following criteria from a plugin called MyCRED to determine whether to display content to the user, however that include consists of shortcodes and other non-PHP content. Is there a way to tell PHP 'treat this as if it is not PHP'? Shortcodes are key.

```
$minimum = 100;
if ( is_user_logged_in() && ( function_exists( 'mycred_get_users_cred' ) && mycred_get_users_cred( get_current_user_id() ) >= $minimum ) ) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) should do the trick.

If your shortcode is just like `[my_shortcode]` then try `echo do_shortcode( '[my_shortcode]' );`

If you have opening and closing then `echo do_shortcode( '[my_shortcode]Inner text[/my_shortcode]' );`

Comment: What if we wanted to include not *only* shortcodes but other content as well?

Comment: Try like this: `echo 'Other content before ' . do_shortcode( '[my_shortcode]Inner text[/my_shortcode]' ) . ' Other content after';` :)

Answer (score 1):

The [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) function should work:

```
echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]');
```